# Loading single images from large tiff stack in Python

Tags: python, tiff, large-files

I'm working in Python on image stacks with up to 1000 images in tiff format. Each image is a 16bit image, 2048x2048 pixels, full size of 8MB, thus the full stack is several GB large. I have three color channels which I merge. The operations I do on the merged stacks (like converting to HSV space, applying filters...) I do on each individual image of the stack.
But when I want to load the full stacks in the beginning, I obviously run out of memory.

Is there a way to handle these large stacks? I had the idea to only load the single images from the stack, do the operations on that individual image, and concatenate it to a stack again. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to do that. Or is there a better solution?
Any help is very much appreciated.

Here is my code so far (where I run out of memory when loading the images, but it works with smaller test stacks):

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import io
import matplotlib

b = io.imread('blue_channel.tif')
g = io.imread('green_channel.tif')
r = io.imread('red_channel.tif')

Npic = np.shape(b)[0]         #get number of images
sizex = np.shape(b)[1]        #get size in x
sizey = np.shape(b)[2]        #get size in y
Ncol = 3

merged_channels = np.zeros([Npic, sizex, sizey, Ncol])
merged_channels[:,:,:,0] = r
merged_channels[:,:,:,1] = g
merged_channels[:,:,:,2] = b

merged_channels = merged_channels.astype(np.float32)          #Cast Image data type      
merged_channels /= 255                                        #Scale value to float32 range 0-1

merged_channels_hsv = np.zeros([Npic, sizex, sizey, Ncol])

for i in tqdm(range(Npic)):
    merged_channels_hsv[i, :, :, :] = matplotlib.colors.rgb_to_hsv(merged_channels[i, :, :, :])

merged_channels_hsv *= 255                                          
merged_channels_hsv = merged_channels_hsv.astype(np.uint8)           

imsave('merged_channels_hsv.tif', merged_channels_hsv[:,:,:,:])
```

Here are sample images:
Merged RGB image:
[image: Merged RGB channels]

Converted to HSV space, only H-channel:
[image: Converted to HSV space, only H-channel]

EDIT:

I found a way to define the image numbers I want to load from a tiff-file using

`skimage.external.tifffile.imread(files, **kwargs)`:

```
import numpy as np
from tifffile import imread

def sequence(start, end):
    res = []
    diff = 1
    x = start
    while x <= end:
        res.append(x)
        x += diff
    return res

seq = sequence(1, 100) #load first 100 images from stack
merged_channels = imread('filename.tif', key = seq)
```

Comment: Can you post sample input images and expected output image?

Comment: I now added two images: The Merged RGB image is one image from a stack. The second image is the hue-channel from the converted image (RGB to HSV conversion). Is this what you asked for?

Comment: Do you have enough memory to read one of the RGB channels? If so you could then split each stack into individual images, then you could them one by one and merge.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get you right: You mean I should load one stack of N images, split it into N single images and save them individually? I get a MemoryError when I initialize the "merged_channels" array. The problem is that I need all three color channels in memory to convert it into HSV space. Assuming I have the merged channels stored in one RGB stack, is there a way to load the individual images from that RGB stack so that I can convert them?